# ng-if to hide/show row when value =0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

The table has columns - ID, PASSED, FAILED  and there is a checkbox -show students with no FAILURES

I can't figure out how to use angular ng-if to bind the checkbox with the table. So if the user checks the checkbox , it should show all rows else only students with no failures. I'm new to angularJS :|

```
<tr>
   <td><span class="CheckBox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Show Students with No Failures</span></td>
</tr>
<tbody >
   <!--display none-->
   <tr ng-repeat="t in table">
      <td colspan="1" ng-hide='t.Failed===0'>{{t.id}}</td>
      <td colspan="1" ng-hide='t.Failed===0'>{{t.Total}</td>
      <td colspan="1" ng-hide='t.Failed===0'>{{t.Passed}}</td>
      <td colspan="1" ng-hide='t.Failed===0'>{{t.Failed}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? What have you tried so far?

Comment: please mention what you have tried

Comment: i can't figure out chaning ng-hide value. Also, found that ng-if was faster so i was trying for ng-if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a implementation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Using a `ng-repeat`in combination with a `filter`.

See [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9dj9j7p5/)

**VIEW**

```
<div id="app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  Only passes students?
  <input type="checkbox" ng-init="passes = true" ng-model="passes">
  <br/> Not passed student students?
  <input type="checkbox" checked ng-init="fails = true" ng-model="fails">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="days">
        <th>Student name</th>
        <th>#FAILS</th>
        <th>PASSED?</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="student in studentData | filter: studentFilter">
        <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.fails }}</td>
        <td>
          {{ (student.fails <=0 ) ? 'YES' : 'NO' }} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.studentFilter = function (item) { 
        if($scope.passes && $scope.fails) return item;
      if($scope.passes && item.fails <= 0) return item;
      if($scope.fails && item.fails > 0) return item;
  };


  $scope.studentData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Nabil',
    fails: 1
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Daan',
    fails: 0
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Walter',
    fails: 2
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Magaly',
    fails: 0
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Steven',
    fails: 2
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Bill',
    fails: 0
  }];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `ng-if` or `ng-show/ng-hide` for this.  I'd use a filter in your in your `ng-repeat` expression to filter the array values.

**filter UI**

```
`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterObj.Failed">`
```

**table**

```
`ng-repeat="t in table | filter:filterObj"`
```

Something along those lines.  Your boolean property keys are a little confusing to me but basically the `filterObj` keys should match with keys found on your table objects.

codepen - http://codepen.io/pen?template=zrGjgW

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a `ng-hide` on each `<td>`, do it on `tr` level. Also, bind to a `ng-model` with your checkbox, to be able to use it:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="CheckBox">
            <input type="checkbox" 
                   ng-model="showNoFailures">Show Students with No Failures
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="t in table"
    ng-if="t.Failed === 0 || showNoFailures">
    <!-- show if all passed, or the cb is checked -->
    <td colspan="1">{{t.id}}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{t.Total}}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{t.Passed}}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{t.Failed}}</td>
</tr>
```

See [this working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29g7s1w5/1/)

Comment: it should show all with failed=0 when checkbox selected otherwise table should show all the rows. And thanks, i understand how to use ng-if now.